# trigger my own jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trigger my own jQuery function using the following but it's not working.  It doesn't even show the alert.  Any ideas?

```
(function($){
    $.fn.loadWorksheets = function() {
    alert("test 123");
        var weekEnding = this.value;
        $.post("fetchRows.php", {week_ending: weekEnding}, function(data)
        {
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("#completedWorksheets > tbody").html("");

            if(data[0] !== false) {
                $(data).each(function(i,val){
                        var newRow = '<tr><td data-th="Week ending">' + data[i]["week_ending"] + '</td><td data-th="Employee">' + data[i]["employee"] + '</td><td data-th="Project">' + data[i]["project"] + '</td><td class="actions"></td></tr>';
                        $("#completedWorksheets tbody").append(newRow);
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#completedWorksheets tbody").append('<tr><td colspan="4">There are no worksheets for the selected week.</td></tr>');
            }
        });
    }
});

$('#week_ending_cm').on('change', function() {
    $.fn.loadWorksheets();
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't intend to use the function as a chainable jQuery plugin, why add it to `$.fn` at all, just use a regular function ?

Comment: I'm primarily a PHP programmer so still pretty new to jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

Your initial anonymous function is not being called.  Its last line should look like

```
})(jQuery);
```

not just

```
});
```

Because the function is not called, the alert isn't shown and your jQuery plugin isn't defined.

As noted in a comment to your question, if you're making a function that isn't intended to be a jQuery method operating on a jQuery object, generally those are added as properties of `$` and not `$.fn`.

Answer (score 6):

Try to replace last string of your function to this:
`})($);`

Comment: More explanation would be good but +1 for posting the first answer that actually works.

Comment: Allthough the answer seems to be right, always try to provide more explanation/code so other random people who looked for this answer understand it as well. :)

Comment: Sorry and now I see that @Pointy explained it perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

Your Js should be like this:
(You were missing the two parenthesis at the end of your function definition block).

```
(function($){
$.fn.loadWorksheets = function() {
alert("test 123");
    var weekEnding = this.value;
    $.post("fetchRows.php", {week_ending: weekEnding}, function(data)
    {
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $("#completedWorksheets > tbody").html("");

        if(data[0] !== false) {
            $(data).each(function(i,val){
                    var newRow = '<tr><td data-th="Week ending">' + data[i]["week_ending"] + '</td><td data-th="Employee">' + data[i]["employee"] + '</td><td data-th="Project">' + data[i]["project"] + '</td><td class="actions"></td></tr>';
                    $("#completedWorksheets tbody").append(newRow);
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#completedWorksheets tbody").append('<tr><td colspan="4">There are no worksheets for the selected week.</td></tr>');
        }
    });
}
})($); // <<<==== HERE WE INSTANTLY CALL IT

$('#week_ending_cm').on('change', function() {
    $.fn.loadWorksheets();
});
```

Comment: some explanation of what you have done would be nice. dont make the op search for hours for the two parenthesis that u've added.

Comment: BTW, then inside anonymous function, `$` is undefined